# Boost variant visitor with variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, stl, boost-mpl, boost-variant

In one of my projects I'm actively using `boost::variant` and I stumbled upon a question I couldn't resolve on my own. I have a `boost::variant` that might contain atomic datatypes and STL containers of these atomic datatypes.

Now, I wanted to compute the size of an instance of the previously defined `boost::variant` type. There are basically only two possible functions. The type of an atomic datatype is simply 1, whereas the size of an STL container is defined as the number of elements contained in it.

Having only 2 atomic dataypes I implemented the following code:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::vector<int>, std::vector<double> > TVariant;

struct sizeVisitor : boost::static_visitor<size_t> {
   size_t operator()(int&) {
    return 1;
    }
   size_t operator()(double&) {
    return 1;
    }

   size_t operator()(std::vector<int>& c) {
    return c.size();
    }

   size_t operator()(std::vector<double>& c) {
    return c.size();
    }
} ;


int main(int argc, char **args) {
    sizeVisitor visitor;
    TVariant var=5;
    std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(visitor, var) << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> vector;
    vector.push_back(6);
    vector.push_back(2);
    var=vector;
    std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(visitor, var) << std::endl;
}
```

As the number of atomic datatypes increases I have a lot of code duplication. I have to declare another two functions for every new atomic datatype, which can be prohibitive.

It would be nice, if the following code would compile:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::vector<int>, std::vector<double> > TVariant;

struct sizeVisitor : boost::static_visitor<size_t> {
   size_t operator()(boost::variant<int,double>&) {
    return 1;
    }

   size_t operator()(boost::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>>& c) {
    return c.size();
    }

} ;


int main(int argc, char **args) {
    sizeVisitor visitor;
    TVariant var=5;
    std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(visitor, var) << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> vector;
    vector.push_back(6);
    vector.push_back(2);
    var=vector;
    std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(visitor, var) << std::endl;
}
```

What might be the closest implementation of the second, unfortunately non-compiling, visitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use two function templates for `operator()`:

```
struct sizeVisitor 
    : boost::static_visitor<size_t>
{
    template <class T>
    size_t operator()(T const&) {
        return 1;
    }

    template <class T>
    size_t operator()(std::vector<T> const& v) {
        return v.size();
    }    
};
```

The template partial ordering rules will ensure that the correct one is called.

Comment: Wow. That's a very obvious solution. Many thanks. I'm wondering if there is also a solution for the more general problem, where I have to divide the set of types of a given `boost::variant` into two subsets, e.g. into numeric and non-numeric. And I wanted to write a visitor yielding a boolean for this property.

Comment: @FrankSimon Use SFINAE - one overload enabled and one disabled depending on some type trait.

Comment: I'm not aware of that concept. Seems that I have to learn a little more about C++. Many thanks for these deep insights. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @FrankSimon Enjoy the rabbit hole you're about to fall into :)

Comment: @frank rather than sfinae, tag dispatch from primary `()` to helper method.  Less confusing, easier, easier to read errors.  `{ return helper(std::is_numeric<T>{}, t); }`, where `helper(true_type, T)` gets the numerics and `helper(false_type, T)` gets the rest.